# Does SQLite support multiple schemas within the same database?

Tags: sqlite

If I look at the [syntax definition of an ALTER TABLE statement](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html), it seems to indicate that a table name can be prefixed with a `schema-name`. Does that mean that SQLite supports schematas (the way SQL Server does)? Or is this `schema-name` referring to another database (similar to MySQL)?

Comment: As there is no `create schema` documented, I would guess that SQLite does not support "real" schemas

Comment: That's my _guess_ too but to be sure I posted this question :) Also, it'd be interesting to know what they are referring to...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In SQLite, a schema name is the name of an [attached database](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html).

So it is not possible to have multiple schemata within the *same* database.

Comment: Isn't first schema `main` and the second one `temp`? : https://sqlite.org/lang_naming.html

Comment: @Pacerier That is a separate [temporary database](http://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html#temp_databases).

Comment: It limits a lot the InMemory uses for testing purposes. If the system under test already has access to different schemas, you'll not be able to use SqLite for it.